# Play Framework: Inject multiple dependencies using constructor injection in the controller

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection

What is the right way to inject multiple dependencies using constructor injection for a controller in Play Framework (2.4.x, which provides guice based DI out of the box) in Scala?

For example,

```
class ExampleController @Inject() (serviceOne: ServiceOne, serviceTwo: ServiceTwo) extends Controller {
}
```

The above won't compile saying only one or no constructor arg can be injected.

Was not able to find any good references regarding as how to get this working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to prepend `val` to the parameters:

```
class ExampleController @Inject() (val serviceOne: ServiceOne, val serviceTwo: ServiceTwo) extends Controller {
```

And also check that you have the correct import:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
```

[Here](https://github.com/anotherhale/play-silhouette-angular-seed/blob/master/app/controllers/CredentialsAuthController.scala) you also can find an example with multiple dependencies, maybe it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. Additionally to that, you need to configure a `module` in your `application.conf`

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.example.HelloModule"
```

And then in this very `Module` you need to describe your dependency injected classes:

```
import play.api.inject._

class HelloModule extends Module {
  def bindings(environment: Environment,
               configuration: Configuration) = Seq(
    bind[Hello].qualifiedWith("en").to[EnglishHello],
    bind[Hello].qualifiedWith("de").to[GermanHello]
  )
}
```

[For the offical documentation see this link.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection)